# Migrate from MySQL to Postgresql

Tags: java, mysql, postgresql, mysql-python

I Installed Postgresql-9.5 and PgAdmin III in my CentOS 6.6, i use these commands,

1) service postgresql-9.5 status

2) service postgresql-9.5 start

3) su postgres

4) psql

5) password

6) mysqldump --compatible=postgresql --default-character-set=utf8 -r databasename.mysql -u root -p databasename

7) mysqldump -u root -p --compatible=postgres databasename < /home/databasename.mysql

> UNLOCK TABLES;
>
> /*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;
>
> /*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
>
>   /*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
>
>   /*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
>
>   /*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;
>
> -- Dump completed on 2017-08-28 11:42:14

Once it completed i open my PgAdmin III and check there is nothing... No data present inside my Database. What mistake I done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mysqldump can't be used for executing SQL commands from file - you need to use something like [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html): `psql -h hostname -d databasename -U username -f file.sql`.

You need to create database before using this command (so remove `create database` from file).

`UNLOCK TABLES;` That will throw error in PostgreSQL, you need to remove that line.

Comment: How to take dump from MySQL to Postgresql Format?

Comment: I haven't done such migration myself, but you could check some of the listed applications in PostgreSQL wiki: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Converting_from_other_Databases_to_PostgreSQL#MySQL or wikibooks: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Converting_MySQL_to_PostgreSQL

Answer (score 0):

An insanely easy approach will be to use [NMIG](https://github.com/AnatolyUss/nmig) an amazing script with near 0 config needed.

1. Clone the repo
2. npm i, npm run build
3. Set your MySQL and Postgres servers connections in the ./config/config.json
4. npm start
5. Enjoy your migrated db